# Toggling divs based on index value using *ngFor and *ngIf in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have two divs which have content based on the index value, is there a way to toggle between the divs passing in an index parameter using *ngIf? But my current approach is not working but I know why, as I am using the toggle by boolean values of `true and false`.

So far I have tried:

```
<div *ngFor="let tab of tabComponents; let i = index;">
   <button
      class="btn btn-secondary mr-2 btn-sm"
      (click)="tab1Click(i)"
      >Tab1</button>
   <button
      class="btn btn-secondary mr-2 btn-sm"
      (click)="tab2Click(i)"
      >Tab2</button>
   <div *ngIf="tab1[i]">Content</div>
   <div *ngIf="tab2[i]">Content</div>
</div>
```

ts.file

```
public tab1 = true;
public tab2 = false;

public tab1Click(i) {
  alert(i);
  public tab1 = true;
  public tab2 = false;
}

public tab2Click(i) {
  alert(i);
  public tab1 = false;
  public tab2 = true;
}
```

I know this does not work because the *ngIf is based on a boolean value or true and false and you can't seem to assign the index to it because of this, this being said is there a way to achieve the toggle based on the index value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it isn't working is because your variables are of type `boolean` (`tab1=true`), but you are trying to access them like they are an array `tab1[i]`

Depending on the desired behavior, you could make the `tab1` and `tab2` boolean arrays:

```
  public tab1: boolean[] = [];
  public tab2: boolean[] = [];

  public tab1Click(i: number) {
    this.tab1[i] = true;
    this.tab2[i] = false;
  }

  public tab2Click(i: number) {
    this.tab1[i] = false;
    this.tab2[i] = true;
  }
```

This will probably get you closed to your desired behavior.

Here's a working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-66449040?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: After re-reading your code, it looks like maybe you are simply trying to display "div 1" when tab one is active and "div 2" when tab two is active.  Is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: Thats great, how would you pass a default value of true or false though?

Comment: Yes that is correct, but each tab content is from the index value

Comment: For default values you could just do: `public tab1: boolean[] = [ true, false ]`.

Comment: Don't know why i didn't see that. But That only sets a default value for the first item?

Comment: Well, yes, you'd need to also set the value for your `tab2` variable. I see you are repeating (in the *ngFor) each tabComponent, which inside has the two content divs that you want to switch between.  This means that each tab has two "sub-divs" that you want toggled a certain way.  Is that correct?  OR were you just wanting to display one of those divs depending which "tab" was active...? something like [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-66449040-otmzc9?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: Yes, so its just the active div based on the index so you can see different tabs in the divs independently

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229429/discussion-between-bizzybob-and-sole).